# Modify the ip address of a network adapter interface

Tags: networking, fedora, network-adapter

ifconfig shows a Network Adapter - **ens37**. I want to modfiy it's ip address to 192.168.26.1/24 
I tried with `ifconfig ens37 192.168.26.1 netmask 255.255.255.0` But that throws an error. 
Any commands or ways to modify the ip/mask of a network adapter interface.
I am running fedora as a virtual machine on VMWARE.

Answer (score 0):

A VMware guest can have a NAT or Bridged Network connection. If you wish to assign your own network IP address, you need to use Bridged Networking and assign an address from the Router.

VMware NAT assigns the guest IP address from the NAT DHCP pool. You cannot assign a NAT address yourself.

Use Bridged Network for what you want to do.